# Where the elasticsearch data is stored?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, elk

I've installed filebeat in a server, collecting all the logs from all the containers i have. With filebeat i indicate to which elasticsearch and kibana hosts he must send them (both, elasticsearch and kibana are running as a service in another server). So now all the logs appear in kibana. My question is, all those logs that appear there, are stored somewhere? In elasticsearch or in kibana?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Data store in Elastic Search, while Kibana is used for visual representational tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the data is stored inside Elasticsearch.

Kibana is a visualization engine on top of Elasticsearch. Kibana itself also stores its configuration data inside an internal Elasticsearch index called `.kibana`.

Whatever you can see from Kibana always comes from Elasticsearch.

You can learn more about Elasticsearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index.html) and Kibana [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html).

Comment: Okay thank you so much. But in the directory /var/lib/elasticsearch i do not have any data directory. I really don't know if the logs are being stored somewhere, or just being indexed from one side to another.

Comment: How did you install ES? From a tarball, RPM, Debian, etc?

Comment: i installed ES, kibana and filebeat as debian packages, and run them as services

Comment: Then, indeed, on Debian `/var/lib/elasticsearch` is the default path where data is normally stored.

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Well, i navigated into that directory, and there is no data folder, only a nodes folder. But when we are talking about data, i mean, when collect log files from filebeat, lets think about first.log, second.log, third.log. All those logs appear in Kibana. My question is, those logs are only indexed, i mean, they are not stored in elasticsearch? If i erase those logs from my server, i mean, from the filebeat input, they are stored somewhere else in elastic?